# Работа ScheduledPool после завершения родительского потока

Tags: java, многопоточность

Здравствуйте. У меня возник такой вот вопрос:в инстансе Runnable у меня есть ссылка на scheduledPool, в run() данного потока я инициализирую этот пул, сабмичу таск и время через которое таск должен выполняться, после чего run() родительского потока сразу завершается, то есть завершается и сам родительский поток и следовательно теряется ссылка на мой пул. Вопрос - будет ли дальше существовать мой пул и содержащийся в нем таск будет выполняться корректно, или его соберет сборщик мусора ?
Спасибо

Comment: возможно тут лучше инициализировать пул не в потоке, а статическим методом, что бы его юзали все кому надо - на то он и пул, возможно надо потоки демонами сделать, но лучше посмотреть в дебагере =)

Comment: А его(пул) никто не юзает. Он просто выполняет таск по прошествии определенного времени и все. 
PS: код этот не написан, поэтому в дебагере смотреть не могу. Хотел вот узнать прежде чем начинать такое имплиментиить

Comment: ну смотри, GC будет пытаться удалить объект, если на нету нету ссылок - если на твой нету, значит, если вероятность, что его удалят сборщик (зависит от алгоритма сборщика).
ну и я понимаю пул - как хранилище ссылок на объект, т.е. если мне, например, надо получить коннект к БД, я обращаюсь в пулу - он дает мне коннект, а по твоему описанию - мне кажется этот просто какой-то объект

Comment: Это все понятно. Просто хотел провести какие то параллели с обычным потоком. Ведь если создать поток и запустить его то он работает несмотря на то что родительский завершился и ссылка на него утеряна

Comment: Базовое свойство потоков-демонов заключается в возможности основного потока приложения завершить выполнение потока-демона (в отличие от обычных потоков) с окончанием кода метода main(), не обращая внимания на то, что поток-демон еще работает.

Comment: При чем тут потоки демоны ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вкратце: да, засабмиченная задача выполнится, более того, перед выходом из `run()` вам необходимо добавить `pool.shutdown()` для того, что GC собрал ваш пул после завершения задач и чтобы JVM вообще завершилась.

Подробнее: провел эксперимент

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ScheduledExecutorService pool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4);
            pool.schedule(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("Running.");
                }
            }, 30000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }
    }.start();

    while (true) {
        new ArrayList<String>(1000);
        Thread.sleep(10);
    }
}
```

Успешно выводит "Running", несмотря на то, что проводится множество сборок мусора.

Пул потоков у `ThreadPoolExecutor` состоит из объектов `Worker` - потоки, которые оборачивают данные им потоки-задачи и выполняют их. Когда вы сабмиттите задачу, в пуле создается и запускается `Worker`. После этого он паркуется в ожидании времени, на которое было назначено выполнение задачи. Так как это активный поток, то GC не может его собрать. А так как `Worker` является внутренним классом для `ThreadPoolExecutor`, то и соответствующий пул тоже не может быть собран (объекты внутренних нестатических классов хранят ссылки на объекты внешних классов). Соответственно, за выполнение задачи переживать нечего.

С другой стороны, после выполнения задачи `Worker` паркуется обратно (не завершая выполнение). Таким образом, GC опять же не может собрать пул. Более того, это работающий вхолостую `Worker` будет препятствовать завершению виртуальной машины.

Cтектрейс для потока `pool-1-thread-1` до (и такой же после) выполнения таски (из JConsole):

> Stack trace: 
> sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
> java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
> java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1987)
> java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue.take(DelayQueue.java:160)
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:609)
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:602)
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:947)
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)